# Modify the legend's text in crystal report 2013 (Service pack 9)

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I'm trying to create a chart with crystal report 2013 (service pack 9) and I wonder how I can change the legend text for the chart, since it doesn't have any option for this purpose ?

Comment: I don't think you can change legend text manually as it is obtained directly from the field taken in the chart.. I am not sure though

Comment: What are you trying to change, specifically? A screenshot would help.